# would like to know if CheckUpkeep() in the Chainlink Keeper interface can be invoked externally?

Tags: chainlink

My objective is to call checkUpkeep() externally to update checkData with data offchain and then have the same passed onchain via performData and performUpkeep()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, checkUpKeep can be set to the `external` access modifier.

Reference: [Chainlink Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/#checkupkeep-function)

Comment: I think external relates to implementation not access. As per the docs it is implemented offchain and called by the node. My question was can it also be invoked by end user.

Comment: For instance, I would like to setup an event counter that is set by an external call to checkUpkeep.